# overloaded method value select with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to select more columns and cast all of them but I receive this error

> "overloaded method value select with alternatives:   (col:
> String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame    (cols:
> org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  cannot be
> applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column,
> String)"

the code is this:

```
val result = df.select(
  col(s"${Constant.CS}_exp.${Constant.DATI_CONTRATTO}.${Constant.NUMERO_CONTRATTO}").cast(IntegerType),
  col(s"${Constant.CS}_exp.${Constant.DATI_CONTRATTO}.${Constant.CODICE_PORTAFOGLIO}").cast(IntegerType), 
  col(s"${Constant.CS}_exp.${Constant.RATEALE}.${Constant.STORIA_DEL_CONTRATTO}"))
```

Comment: I think the error means the compiler is not sure which select method to use. Don't you have more error message (multiple lines)?

Comment: @Juh_ Yes this is the full error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column, String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of the error message means that the compiler cannot find a method "select" with an api that fit your code: `select(Column, Column, String)`

However, the compiler found 2 possible methods, but they don't fit:

- `select(col: String, cols: String*)`
- `select(cols: Column*)`
  (the `*` means "any number of")

This, I am sure of.

However, I don't understand why you get that error with the code you've given that actually is `select(Column, Column, Column)` which fits the `select(cols: Column*)` api. For some reason, it consider the last argument to be a `String`. Maybe some parenthesis are wrongly placed

What I do in such cases, is to split the code to validate types:

```
val col1: Column = col(s"${Constant.CS}_exp.${Constant.DATI_CONTRATTO}.${Constant.NUMERO_CONTRATTO}").cast(IntegerType)
val col2: Column = col(s"${Constant.CS}_exp.${Constant.DATI_CONTRATTO}.${Constant.CODICE_PORTAFOGLIO}").cast(IntegerType)
val col3: Column = col(s"${Constant.CS}_exp.${Constant.RATEALE}.${Constant.STORIA_DEL_CONTRATTO}")

val result = df.select(col1, col2, col3)
```

and check it compiles alright